# Sum based on distinct values of a sibling node

Tags: xslt, foreach, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to figure out a way sum values based a distinct ID in my xml, but have been unsuccessful. I'm grouping entries by on data element, but I'm trying to sum the amt node based on unique values of the id rather than just sum all instances of amt.

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Records>
    <Entry>
        <Result>
            <id>123</id>
            <amt>80.00</amt>
        </Result>
        <data1>KEY</data1>
        <data2/>
        <data3/>
        <dataN/>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Result>
            <id>123</id>
            <amt>80.00</amt>
        </Result>
        <data1>KEY</data1>
        <data2/>
        <data3/>
        <dataN/>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Result>
            <id>123</id>
            <amt>80</amt>
        </Result>
        <data1>KEY1</data1>
        <data2/>
        <data3/>
        <dataN/>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Result>
            <id>ABC</id>
            <amt>120.25</amt>
        </Result>
        <data1>KEY</data1>
        <data2/>
        <data3/>
        <dataN/>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Result>
            <id>ABC</id>
            <amt>120.25</amt>
        </Result>
        <data1>KEY</data1>
        <data2/>
        <data3/>
        <dataN/>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Result>
            <id>ABC</id>
            <amt>120.25</amt>
        </Result>
        <data1>KEY</data1>
        <data2/>
        <data3/>
        <dataN/>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Result>
            <id>ABC</id>
            <amt>120.25</amt>
        </Result>
        <data1>KEY</data1>
        <data2/>
        <data3/>
        <dataN/>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Result>
            <id>AB90</id>
            <amt>75.00</amt>
        </Result>
        <data1>KEY2</data1>
        <data2/>
        <data3/>
        <dataN/>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Result>
            <id>AB90</id>
            <amt>75.00</amt>
        </Result>
        <data1>KEY2</data1>
        <data2/>
        <data3/>
        <dataN/>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Result>
            <id>XYZ</id>
            <amt>75.00</amt>
        </Result>
        <data1>KEY2</data1>
        <data2/>
        <data3/>
        <dataN/>
    </Entry>
</Records>
```

Here is a simplified desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Records>
    <Entry>
        <amt>200.25</amt>
        <relatedData>
            <data1>KEY</data>
            <data2/>
            <data3/>
            <dataN/> 
        </relatedData>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
      <amt>80</amt>
      <relatedData>
         <data1>KEY1</data1>
         <data2/>
         <data3/>
         <dataN/>
      </relatedData>
   </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <amt>150.00</amt> 
        <relatedData>
            <data1>KEY2</data>
            <data2/>
            <data3/>
            <dataN/> 
        </relatedData>
    </Entry>
</Records>
```

I have an xslt like this currently, but I need to be able to determine unique IDs rather than amounts. I'm using the xslt below but getting the wrong result for the final Entry as it's considering 75.00 to be a unique amt rather seeing they are from 2 unique entries.

Current XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Records">

        <root>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Entry" group-by="data1">
                <Entry>
                    <!-- Sum just amounts from unique entry IDs -->
                    <!-- Doesn't account for unique entry IDs -->
                    <amt>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(distinct-values(current-group()/Result/amt))"/>
                    </amt>

                    <!-- output related data -->
                    <relatedData>
                        <data1>
                            <xsl:value-of select="data1"/>
                        </data1>
                        <!-- Place holder code
                        <data2>
                            <xsl:value-of select='sum(current-group()/data2)'/>
                        </data2>
                        <data3>
                            <xsl:value-of select='sum(current-group()/data3)'/>
                        </data3>
                        -->
                    </relatedData>
                </Entry>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

current output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Entry>
      <amt>200.25</amt>
      <relatedData>
         <data1>KEY</data1>
      </relatedData>
   </Entry>
   <Entry>
      <amt>80</amt>
      <relatedData>
         <data1>KEY1</data1>
      </relatedData>
   </Entry>
   <Entry>
      <!-- incorrect total, should be 150 -->
      <amt>75</amt>
      <relatedData>
         <data1>KEY2</data1>
      </relatedData>
   </Entry>
</root>
```

Comment: Can it be assumed that every duplicate `id` has the same `amt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to do something like:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Records">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Entry" group-by="data1">
            <xsl:variable name="sub-groups">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="Result/id">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Result/amt"/>
                 </xsl:for-each-group>  
            </xsl:variable>
            <Entry>
                <amt>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum($sub-groups/amt)"/>
                </amt>
                <relatedData>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="* except Result"/>
                </relatedData>
            </Entry>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works great - thank you! I had an idea I could use a variable but it wasn't coming to me. Thanks again!